# MySQL - Join three tables and display data (even if no match is found)

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that joins **three** tables:

1. specialties { id, name, description, image }
2. doctors { id, name, description, photo }
3. doc_spec { id, id_doc, id_spec }

   ```
   SELECT
      d.id,
      d.name,
      d.description,
      d.photo,
      GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'specialty'
   FROM
      doc_spec ds
   INNER JOIN
      doctors d
   ON
      ds.id_doc=d.id
   INNER JOIN
      specialties s
   ON
      ds.id_spec=s.id
   GROUP BY
      d.id
   ```

The query is working perfectly to retrieve the data from the two tables using the doc_spec table that connects the other two but the problem is when i have a doctor that does **not** have a designated specialty.

What can i do so that instead of not showing the row when there isn't a match on the doc_spec table it retrieves the row anyway with a NULL value on the specialty column? If possible instead of showing null if it could hold a value of something like "No specialty designated" it would be perfect.

**UPDATE**

I found a way to do it by using RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN but i'm not sure if it is the correct way to do so and i still would like to be able to hold a value like "No specialty designated" instead of null.

```
    SELECT
       d.id,
       d.name,
       d.description,
       d.photo,
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'specialty'
    FROM
       doc_spec ds
    RIGHT JOIN
       doctors d
    ON
       ds.id_doc=d.id
    LEFT JOIN
       specialties s
    ON
       ds.id_spec=s.id
    GROUP BY
       d.id
```

Comment: Have you tried a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Does not work with just **left** but if works if i use both **right** and **left**, thanks

Comment: Ah yes, did not see you start with `doc_specs`. Very good.

Comment: Sort your data from left to right, where most left is primary, and all the following datas are less important. So you have only left joins left. If the data is mandatory, do an inner join, if its optional, use an outer join. Looks like your problem is, you have the data you need most not on the top-left or top-right position in table ordering.

Comment: I see, @DanFromGermany . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT
   d.id,
   d.name,
   d.description,
   d.photo,
   IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(s.name SEPARATOR ', '), 'No specialities') AS 'specialty'
FROM
   doc_spec ds
RIGHT JOIN
   doctors d
ON
   ds.id_doc=d.id
LEFT JOIN
   specialities s
ON
   ds.id_spec=s.id
GROUP BY
   d.id
```

Comment: Why -1? Can you tell me?

Comment: Hello, @vookash, it worked perfectly it was just what i was looking for. Thanks. As for the -1 is was **not** me.

Comment: I'm glad i could help :)